# How do I specify events deep inside "Applications and Services Logs"?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, event-log

The following code snippet fires an event when an event is logged. The sample code works fine but the log I want to monitor is actually "Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Task Scheduler > Operational".

What do I insert in place of "Application" in the code sample?

```
...
EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog("Application", ".", "testEventLogEvent");                 

myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log name is `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational` but I don't think you can access it using the EventLog class.  I think that log is based on Event Tracing for Windows so you need to use the [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.aspx) to access it.

The [Event Log Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671204.aspx) page might be useful, in particular the [How to: Subscribe to Events in an Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202.aspx) article might help you get started.

**Update**: The How to: Subscribe to Events in an Event Log code worked for me after I changed the log name (I also changed the query to request Level=4)...

```
EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(
    "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=4]");
```