# Clear EventLog Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I am trying to clear event log in on my Windows 7. In documentation I found this example:

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog("MySource");
eventLog.Source = "MySource";
eventLog.Clear();
```

It's working fine for logs in Windows Application and Services Logs folder. But my logs are located in "Application and Services-Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational". And I get an error:

> The event log 'PrintService' on computer does not exist.

[Here is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyQfd.png)

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572378/how-do-i-programmatically-or-regularly-clear-the-operational-printservice-event) would help you?

Comment: it works, thanks. But how do it by C#