# Reading latest event log details

Tags: c#, printing, event-log

So i have been monitoring my print jobs through event logs and it works quite well, now i wanted to get the number of copies it is printing but the problem is it reads the oldest event log instead of the latest one.

```
private void checkCopies()
    {
        EventLogQuery logQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(EventID = 805)]]");
        EventLogWatcher logWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(logQuery);
        EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(logQuery);
        logWatcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(getCopies);
        logWatcher.Enabled = true;
    }
private void getCopies(Object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
    {
        EventLogQuery logQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(EventID = 805)]]");
        EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(logQuery);
        EventRecord rec = logReader.ReadEvent();
        if (rec != null)
            totalCopies = rec.ToXml().ToString();
    }
private void getPrintedCopies()
    {
        Regex parts = new Regex(@"<Copies>(\d+)</Copies>");
        Match match = parts.Match(totalCopies);
        if (match.Success)
            copies = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

how do i make it so that it reads the latest log instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found some kind of solution by clearing the event logs for PrintService which can be found here:

[How do I programmatically or regularly clear the Operational PrintService event log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572378/how-do-i-programmatically-or-regularly-clear-the-operational-printservice-event?rq=1)

Now i can get the number of copies and number of pages for my print job monitoring app.